# currentPlaybackTime & NSTimer to launch views during a video and be correctly launched/relaunched when time point positioned with the scrubber

Tags: xcode, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, nstimer

Struggling here...

I am trying to have views displayed during specific periods in a videos timeline, being replaced when the next view is triggered. This much I have managed to do - my problem is that this only happens in a linear fashion and if the playhead is moved back to a view that has already been triggered (ie anything prior to that point) the timer continues on, but the triggers are no longer firing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!  Here's the code...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    keyframeTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    shoutOutTexts = [[NSArray 
                      arrayWithObjects:@"This is a test\nLabel at 2 secs ", 
                      @"This is a test\nLabel at 325 secs",
                      nil] retain];
    shoutOutTimes = [[NSArray 
                      arrayWithObjects:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 2], 
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 325],
                      nil] retain];



    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    self.player.contentURL = [self movieURL];
    // END:viewDidLoad1


    self.player.view.frame = self.viewForMovie.bounds;
    self.player.view.autoresizingMask = 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [self.viewForMovie addSubview:player.view];
    [self.player play];
    // START_HIGHLIGHT  

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    // END_HIGHLIGHT    

    // START:viewDidLoad1

    [self.view addSubview:self.myScrollView];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(movieDurationAvailable:)
     name:MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification
     object:nil];
}
// END:viewDidLoad
// END:viewDidLoad1

// START:movieURL
-(NSURL *)movieURL
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = 
    [bundle 
     pathForResource:@"BigBuckBunny_640x360" 
     ofType:@"m4v"];
    if (moviePath) {
        return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
// END:movieURL

int position = 0;

- (void)timerAction:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    NSLog(@"hi");
    int count = [shoutOutTimes count];
    NSLog(@"count is at %d", count);

    if (position < count) {
        NSNumber *timeObj = [shoutOutTimes objectAtIndex:position];
        int time = [timeObj intValue];
        NSLog(@"time is at %d", time);
        if (self.player.currentPlaybackTime >= time) {
            CommentView *cview = [[CommentView alloc] 
                                  initWithText:[shoutOutTexts objectAtIndex:position]];
            [self.player.view addSubview:cview];
            position++;
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0f target:self selector:@selector(removeView:) userInfo:cview repeats:NO];
        }
    }

}

- (void)removeView:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    UIView *view = [theTimer userInfo];
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Here's the log calls Till...

Here's the log calls...

```
2011-04-23 11:53:44.370 MoviePlayer[17129:207] last check was at 7.76279
2011-04-23 11:53:44.371 MoviePlayer[17129:207] current playback time is 8.76292
2011-04-23 11:53:44.371 MoviePlayer[17129:207] shouting: This is a test
Label at 2 secs
2011-04-23 11:53:45.368 MoviePlayer[17129:207] position is at 2
2011-04-23 11:53:45.369 MoviePlayer[17129:207] shout scheduled for 8
2011-04-23 11:53:45.370 MoviePlayer[17129:207] last check was at 8.76451
2011-04-23 11:53:45.371 MoviePlayer[17129:207] current playback time is 9.76299
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because `position` is a static variable and you are always raising it but never lowering it.

You will need to change the logic within the timer function a little - maybe like this;

Remove the static variable `position` from your source (`int position = 0;`)

```
- (NSInteger)positionFromPlaybackTime:(NSTimeInterval)playbackTime
{
  NSInteger position = 0;
  for (NSNumber *startsAt in shoutOutTimes)
  {
    if (playbackTime > [startsAt floatValue])
    {
      ++position;
    }
  }
  return position;
}
```

Add a static variable (actually an instance variable would be cleaner but hey, we are just trying to get it to work at this moment):

```
NSTimeInterval lastCheckAt = -1.0;
```

Then change your timer method to this:

```
- (void)timerAction:(NSTimer*)theTimer 
{
    int count = [shoutOutTimes count];

    NSInteger position = [self positionFromPlaybackTime:self.player.currentPlaybackTime];

    NSLog(@"position is at %d", position);
    if (position > 0)
    {
        --position;
    }
    if (position < count) 
    {
        NSNumber *timeObj = [shoutOutTimes objectAtIndex:position];
        int time = [timeObj intValue];

        NSLog(@"shout scheduled for %d", time);
        NSLog(@"last check was at %g", lastCheckAt);
        NSLog(@"current playback time is %g", self.player.currentPlaybackTime);

        if (lastCheckAt < time && self.player.currentPlaybackTime >= time)
        {
            NSString *shoutString = [shoutOutTexts objectAtIndex:position];

            NSLog(@"shouting: %@", shoutString);

            CommentView *cview = [[CommentView alloc] initWithText:shoutString];
            [self.player.view addSubview:cview];
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0f target:self selector:@selector(removeView:) userInfo:cview repeats:NO];
        }
    }
    lastCheckAt = self.player.currentPlaybackTime;
}
```

Comment: Note; this is highly unoptimized and really is mostly for making as little changes to your code as needed. I would generally advise not to iterate through an array within a timer triggered method if that array could potentially be pretty big. For your example however, this should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for that! Seriously appreciate your time! The timer seems to be working beautifully in the log. Unfortunately the shoutOuts now don't appear. I've had a fiddle but don't seem to be able to figure it out - Any thoughts?

Comment: I can not see how the actual display code would have changed. I have added a bit of logging (shouting: %@) to get closer to the issue. Do we see that in the logs? Ow, one more thing. As a token of your appreciation, once the issue is solved, you could upvote my answer and mark it as accepted (upwards arrow, checkmark close to my answer).

Comment: Of course I will - least I can do! I'll send you a promo code for the app I am updating too if you'd like... Also, you might want to check your website out - Safari is giving a major 'malicious' warning after I clicked the link to it - Just thought I'd let you know...

Comment: Possibly relevant - If the first shoutout is at 2 seconds, nothing is shown at any of the points. If the first shoutout is at 0 seconds, the first one works fine, but none of the following do. Seemed interesting enough to mention. Log above updated..

Comment: After reading a bit within your logs and thinking things through more thoroughly, I realized that we are actually having two issues: 1. shouting is never triggered 2. if it was triggered, it would be triggered far too often.... updating my answer again (within 5mins).

Comment: I have modified the code. This should take care of issue 2 - I still am unsure on why we have issue 1. But getting closer, i bet.

Comment: Where did you declare 'shoutedAt'?

Comment: If I take out if (lastCheckAt < time && self.player.currentPlaybackTime >= time)
       { and 
   lastCheckAt = self.player.currentPlaybackTime;
}   it works but about 2 seconds out of sync...

Comment: Updated sources, try again with my version

Comment: Looking good! Only thing is it is launching the commentView correctly at the time point, also if I slide back and forth in the vid, but the shoutText is coming in one time slot later than listed. Cheers.... Shown in new log above...

Comment: Oh, and not launching the last one too.

Comment: Fixed it!!! NSString *shoutString = [shoutOutTexts objectAtIndex:position +1]; How annoying is that! ;-)

Comment: If you want to add that to your fix, I'll do all the ticks and buttons etc. A seriously big thanks you too!!! Would you like this promo code for the app? If so, where would you like it sent?

Comment: Can't up vote sadly as my rep isn't above 15. As soon as it is I'll be sure to pop back and do so.

Comment: No worries - sorry for all those iterations, never really tried the code I posted. Sent a mail to the contact listed on your site - not sure if that reaches you.

Comment: Hey there... One last question on this - Have you got any idea how I can stop this timer on leaving the view - I've tried just about everything I can think of and in the docs, but nothing seems to work. Any thoughts?